# How to send user data using SendMessage function?

Tags: c++, winapi

How to send struct or pointer using SendMessage or PostMessage function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is simple example:

```
typedesf struct tagMY_STRUCT{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int c;
}MY_STRUCT;

//Some code which sends message
MY_STRUCT *pStruct = new MY_STRUCT;

pStruct->a = 5;
pStruct->b = 4;
pStruct->c = 1;

SendMessage(hWnd, WM_USER + 1, 0, (LPARAM)pStruct);

//WndProc

case (WM_USER + 1) :
{
    MY_STRUCT *pStruct = (MY_STRUCT*)lParam);
    if(pStruct)
    {
        int a = pStruct->a;

        delete pStruct;
    }

}
break;
```

- Don't ever try to do it between processes.Study IPC basics first.
- Don't forget to release pointer to struct once not needed using
  **delete**.

**UPDATE**

As **Remy Lebeau** mentioned in comment, you can also allocate struct on stack instead on heap using new/malloc, because [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) block thread until it's processed in WndProc.This does not apply to [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which add message to window's message queue and return immediately, so it requires heap block.

However, if you plan to pass more complex data struct I recommend heap allocation instead of stack.

Comment: `SendMessage()` is synchronous, so you don't need to use `new` to allocate the struct dynamically.  You can allocate it on the stack instead and just pass its pointer to `SendMessage()`. The receiver does not need to free it. `PostMessage()`, on the other hand, is asynchronous, so the `new/delete` approach is necessary.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : +1, You are correct, but imagine that you need to pass much bigger struct/data block, then this is more convenient way.However, you have right.

Comment: Even with larger data, using `SendMessage()`, the receiver should not free the memory, the sender should after `SendMessage()` exits.

Comment: Disagree, several win32 API do it that way.API allocates, caller free.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - re. SendMessage, yes, strictly you are right, as long as the receiver does not retain ownership of the passed object or further communicate it on, you will be fine with a stack object.  I deliberately did not go into such detail - passing pointers to stack objects around on inter-thread comms is just too dangerous overall in any non-trivial multithreaded apps.  Developers tend to store or forward objects and don't like having then automagically vanish at some pseudo-random point because of a return on another stack in another module.

Comment: Unless otherwise documented, a receiver should not assume that a received pointer will remain valid once the message is finished being processed. If the receiver needs to take ownership of the data, it should create its own copy of the data, not take ownership of the original.

Comment: @rkosegi: name a Win32 API message where the receiver is supposed to free the memory being passed in the message. Having an API function allocate memory that the caller is supposed to free is a completely different programming model than what we are discusing here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau err.. not to much.  Copying large, complex objects is expensive at best and insanely dangerous at worst.  It's safer by far for the norm to be that the receiver assumes ownership of the object unless otherwise documented.  Do you really like writing complex copy ctors?

Comment: @RemyLebeau almost all networking functions : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and several OLE functions. What do thing why exist CoTaskMemFree and NetApiBufferFree  ??

Comment: @rkosegi: we're not talking about function calls, we're talking about window messages.  Yes, many function calls allocate memory that the caller has to free. Most window messages, on the other hand, do not pass around memory that the message handler is supposed to free. That is certainly true for Win32 API messages, anyway. Custom messages, on the other hand, are at the descretion of the developer to decide who allocates and frees memory.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau ,ok, but situation is same.I understand that OP is 'pushing' data to WndProc in opposite to my examples of API calls where callers request some data from API, but I just want to defend method where one part of program allocates heap memory block, and other ones free it.No offense, I accept your objections, I just want to explain why I consider this method usable.Imagine that OP will try to did it with PostMessage...you know what can happens.don't worry.You mean I should somehow change my answer?I don't think so.

Comment: @rkosegi - yes, Remy does have a point that SendMessage() type synchronous inter-thread comms will work OK providing that the receiver doesn't keep the object pointer for later or communicate it off to yet another thread.  Unfortunately, doing exactly that is very common and I think that it is unreasonable and unsafe for a WndProc to get an object in a custom message that vaporises upon return - the WndProc, and function/s called from it, cannot easily tell whether an object has been posted or sent & so, IMHO, it's safer to not use stack-based objects for any inter-thread comms at all, ever.

Comment: Is "Caller allocate callee frees" an acceptable technique? I always though it is wrong as the callee doesn't know if the caller needs the object anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Send/Post it to where?

In general, an in-process communication by casting a pointer to LParam or WParam at one end and casting it back at the other is fairly straightforward. Don't create objects/structs/whatever on local stacks, especially when PostMessaging - use dynamic allocation with new().  Consider the object lifetime - if the receiver does not need to keep a PostMessaged object or pass it on, it should delete() it.

For inter-process comms, Google for 'WM_COPYDATA'.

Comment: I have struct with 3 unsigned int values. I need to send it to WndProc.

Comment: Then it's fairly easy - @rkosegi has posted an example.  As he/she hints at, inter-process comms is a bit more complex - you must have a handle to the target window, use the WM_COPYDATA message number and SendMessage with a special structure to copy your data into.